# Android Studio 3.0 Proguard using kotlin & greendao returns ClassLookupException

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

The full exception is:

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.ClassLookupException: Invalid class reference: java/rmi/server/RemoteStub
>
> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.ClassLookupException: Invalid class reference: java/rmi/server/RemoteStub
>
> Error:com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.ClassLookupException: Invalid class reference: java/rmi/server/RemoteStub

I am using Kotlin and GreenDao.

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.0.0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'GreenDAODatabaseName', '"App_Database"'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

The second gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

All I did so far in the application is add a few UI classes (fragment and activity) written in kotlin.
Two entities exist for greenDAO. Before I added kotlin proguard worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

GreenDAO doesn't support Kotlin yet (see [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/395)).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this order?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Like deviant-studio said [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/395?#issuecomment-324380675)